# Sanity environment variable

Tags: gatsby, sanity

Hi I am currently trying to set a sanity environment variable in the sanity folder.
According to the sanity documentation, it says to use process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_VARIABLE_NAME but looks like it doesn't get detected and I get an error.

I have also tried using SANITY_ACTIVE_ENV but did not work as well.
Is there a way to set environment variable for sanity?

When I am using it I type-

authorization: `bearer ${process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_NAME}`

I have tried naming the env file as .env and .env.local. Both don't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What documentation reference are you using?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ  https://www.sanity.io/docs/environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby ignores env variables without `GATSBY_` prefix. So, the easiest way is to install and use the "gatsby-plugin-env-variables". The `.env` file in the project root is fine.

Your gatsby-config.js would be extended with

```
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-env-variables',
      options: {
        allowList: ["SANITY_STUDIO_NAME"]
      },
    },
  ]
```